When I use the Spark BigQuery connector to read BQ data, is the storage API always used?
I'm using the Spark BigQuery Connector to read Big Query data in Spark. I know there are a few ways to do this:

one of which uses only the Storage API to read in data
another that runs a BigQuery query in BigQuery using slots.

My question: in option 2, once my BigQuery query completes and materializes the results in BigQuery, does the Spark Connector then use the Storage Read API to read those materialized results into my dataframe? Or does something else happen?
I was unable to find confirmation in the documentation. I know when slots used and when they aren't, but I want to confirm that the Storage API is always the mechanism by which data is read into Spark from BQ.

Answer: Yes, the Spark-BigQuery connector executes a BigQuery query over the view and uses the Storage Read API to read from the resulting table.
Confirmation: In the Storage API documentation, the first point under limitations is:

Because the Storage Read API operates on storage, you cannot use the Storage Read API to directly read from logical or materialized views. As a workaround, you can execute a BigQuery query over the view and use the Storage Read API to read from the resulting table. Some connectors, including the Spark-BigQuery connector, support this workflow natively.

The last line confirms your doubt.

While I don't know for sure how the data is retrieved from BigQuery following a query, I would be surprised if it were anything other than using the Storage API.  I am assuming that the core of your question comes from trying to determine the cost of using BigQuery.  Google charges a fee for data retrieved from tables using Storage Read API.  However, that fee is waved if the data you are retrieving is from the result of a previous query.  My evidence for this is this article which states:

Note: You are not charged for data extraction or data transfer when accessing query results in the Google Cloud console, BigQuery API, or any other clients, such as Looker.

The key phrase to me is query results.  It seems Google distinguishes from raw table reads (point at table, get the data) and raw query results (issue a query, get the query results data).
